# allAuthenticatedUsers for a cloudFunction to send a push notification: perl client side code

Tags: firebase, perl, google-cloud-functions

I have written a HTTP cloud function called `send_push`. It basically receives payload from a perl script and sends out push notifications via FCM to the tokens provided. Tested it in unauthenticated mode and everything works well. This "perl script" is open source. People download that perl script and use it to send notifications to my mobile app (which they buy from the app/play store). So obviously, the perl script cannot come with any of my secrets or service accounts.

I now want to add authentication to that cloud function. My goal is to allow my function to be called by any user who is signed into google using **their own credentials**. To enable this, I've gone to `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/<myproject>/authentication/providers` and enabled "Email/password" and "google" in the hopes that anyone who signs up using an email/password or directly via google login can then invoke my function. I've also enabled `allAuthenticatedUsers` for my `send_push` function and removed `allUsers`

Have I made the right assumptions? I've been going around in loops trying to parse the cloud functions authentication [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam).

If I have made the right assumptions, what libraries can I use on the perl script side that can prompt the user to enter their login credentials (via google or email sign up) and then use that data to generate and refresh tokens? They won't have `gcloud` installed, so I can't do things like `$(gcloud auth print-identity-token)` for authentication, which I think anyway is for developers.

Note that the [sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint) cloud authentication code shows how my endpoint can authenticate against firebase users that have registered with _my_app. This is not what I want.